# how to connect to netsuite use java application

Tags: java, netsuite

i have setup Oauth version 1 on my java for connect to netsuite.. and for authorization there is no problem. but when i hit their endpoint i got response like this

```
{
    "pagination": null,
    "data": null,
    "error": {
        "status": true,
        "message": "400 Bad Request: [{\"error\" : {\"code\" : \"INVALID_REQUEST\", \"message\" : \"The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.\"}}]",
        "code": 1003
    }
}
```

maybe someone here can help me for give some feedback for documentation for netsuite or something ?

here my code for request

```
{
 "record_type": "location",
 "data": [
   {
     "location_id_wms": 1404,
     "name": "KEM - Denver",
     "parent_location": "",
     "address1": "test",
     "address2": "TEST",
     "country": "USA",
     "city": "Test",
     "status_hub":"yes",
     "bad_location": "",
     "lost_location": "",
     "location_type_wms": "Store",
     "location_group": "Denver"
   }
 ]
}
```

and here when i set my request on java

@Override

```
  public void integrationLocationMaster(StructureIntegrationRequest structureIntegrationRequest, String auth) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, JsonProcessingException {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        final String baseUrl = "https://customerCode.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl";
        headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, getAuthHeader(baseUrl));
        System.out.println(getAuthHeader(baseUrl));
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        System.out.println(headers.get(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE));
        headers.setContentLength(mapper.writeValueAsString(structureIntegrationRequest).length());
        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(structureIntegrationRequest, headers);


        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(structureIntegrationRequest));
        URI uri = null;
        try {
            uri = new URI(baseUrl+"?script=56&deploy=1");
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Can you show your request?